# py2exe error when compiling

Tags: python, py2exe

i was made some python script and i want to make this script to exe file.

but when compiling this script to exe, some error encounter i was try to resolve this problem

but no luck.

following is script source

if anyone can help me really much appreciate!

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import lxml,cookielib,urllib,configobj,sys,getopt,string,mechanize,time,os 
from lxml import etree
from lxml.html import parse, fromstring
import sys, getopt, string  
import lxml.html

br = mechanize.Browser()
cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
br.set_cookiejar(cj)
br.set_handle_equiv(True)
br.set_handle_gzip(True)
br.set_handle_redirect(True)
br.set_handle_referer(True)
br.set_handle_robots(False)

# Follows refresh 0 but not hangs on refresh > 0
br.set_handle_refresh(mechanize._http.HTTPRefreshProcessor(), max_time=1)

# Want debugging messages?
br.set_debug_http(False)
br.set_debug_redirects(False)
br.set_debug_responses(False)

# User-Agent (this is cheating, ok?)
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; SV1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)')]

SAVEFILE= 'betextract.txt'
post_count = 0
mac = ''
def getMacAddress():
      if sys.platform == 'win32':
        for line in os.popen("ipconfig /all"):
          if line.lstrip().startswith('Physical Address'):
            mac = line.split(':')[1].strip().replace('-',':')
            break
      else:
        for line in os.popen("/sbin/ifconfig"):
          if line.find('Ether') > -1:
            mac = line.split()[4]
            break
      return mac 
      print mac
getMacAddress()
print mac
def safeunicode(s):
      s = str(s).decode('utf-8')
      try:
        return s.encode('euc-kr').decode('cp949')
      except UnicodeDecodeError:
        return s

#check_demo()
#from configobj import ConfigObj Template 화일 불러오기 ini
config = configobj.ConfigObj('config.ini')
section1 = config['NAVERPASS']
section2 = config['NAVERID']
section3 = config['Nblogkeyword']
section4 = config['end_line']
section5 = config['Content']
section6 = config['HongboSubject']
section7 = config['HongboBody']

NAVERPASS     = section1['NAVERPASS']
NAVERID       = section2['NAVERID']
Nblogkeyword  = section3['Nblogkeyword']
end_line       = section4['end_line']
Content       = section5['Content']
HongboSubject = section6['HongboSubject']
HongboBody    = section7['HongboBody']

enkw = str(Nblogkeyword).decode('cp949')

#아래부분에서 빼기를 위한 int로 변환
end_line       = int(section4['end_line'])
start_line = 0
while end_line: 
    #end_line = end_line - 9
    form = {
        'where': 'post',
        'sm' : 'ab_pge',
        'query' : enkw,
        'st' : 'sim',
        'date_option' : '-1',
        'date_from' : '',
        'date_to' : '',
        'dup_remove' : '1',
        'post_blogid' : '',
        'post_blogurl' : '',
        'post_blogurl_without' : '',
        'detail_and_query' : '',
        'detail_not_query' : '',
        'detail_or_query' : '' ,
        'detail_udp_query' : '',
        'srchby' : 'all',
        'nso' : 'so%3Ar%2Ca%3Aall%2Cp%3A',
        'ie' : 'utf8',
        'start' : start_line
      }
    qstring = urllib.urlencode(form)
    f = urllib.urlopen('http://cafeblog.search.naver.com/search.naver?%s' %qstring)
    html = f.read()
    f.close()
    start_line += 10
    end_line = end_line - 10
    s= []
    html = lxml.html.fromstring(html)
    save = open(SAVEFILE, 'w+')
    for content in html.cssselect('li.sh_blog_top'):
        try:
            subject = content.cssselect('dl dt a.sh_blog_title b')[0].text_content()
            body = content.cssselect('dl dd.sh_blog_passage')[0].text_content()
            print u'[+추출중+] %s | %s ' %(subject , body)

            chen = '%s|%s' %(subject, body)  #중요 이런식으로 처리를 해야함 꼭 인코딩!
            title2 = chen.encode('cp949')
            save.write(title2 + '\n')            
        except Exception, err:
            sys.stderr.write(u'에러발생 => 에러 자동처리중... %s\n' % str(err))
            content = ''
            break


    save.close()
    #print  subject  , body
    #s.append(subject)
    #s.append(body)
    #print '|'.join(s)


## Show the response headers
#print br.info()
## or
##print br.response().info()
#for link in br.links():
    #print link
br.open('http://nid.naver.com/nidlogin.login')
#for f in br.forms():
    #print f

br.select_form(nr=0)
br.form['id']=NAVERID
br.form['pw']=NAVERPASS
#br.click(type="submit", nr=0)
#print br.forms()
#br.submit(name="URL", nr=0)
#html = br.response().read()
#print html
br.form.action='https://nid.naver.com/nidlogin.login'    #javascript source analysis!! have to find inside javascript source
br.submit()
html = br.response().read()
#decoded = br.response().read().decode('utf-8')
#print html
br.open('http://m.blog.naver.com/')
save = open(SAVEFILE)
for line in save:
    sub = line.split('|')[0]
    con = line.split('|')[1].replace('\n', '')
    #print sub, con

    br.open('http://m.blog.naver.com/PostWriteForm.nhn?blogId=ylgwn&categoryNo=')
    #print br.response().read()    
    #for f in br.forms():
        #print f   
    br.select_form(nr=0)
    entest = "%s"  %(sub)
    br.form['post.title']= sub.decode('cp949') + HongboSubject.decode('cp949')
    br.form['post.contents.contentsValue']= con.decode('cp949') + HongboBody.decode('cp949')
    #req = br.click_link(text=u'확인')
    #br.open(req)
    #br.form.click(kind="clickable")
    #for link in br.links():
        #print link
    #br.follow_link(nr=1

    #br.follow_link(text=u"확인")
    #req = br.click(type="submit")
    #br.open(req)   
    br.form.action='http://m.blog.naver.com/PostWrite.nhn'
    br.submit()
    post_count += 1
    print  str(post_count ) +u'개 글올리기 성공!!'  
save.close()
print u'블로그 글올리기 완료!'
```

Comment: What is the error? Saying "some error" is not very specific and makes it fairly difficult to help.

Comment: Hello..i was used to make exe file by use py2exe .

Comment: Yes, I understand that. My question, though, is what *specific* error are you getting? There are a lot of things that could be causing an error, and posting "some error encounter" and a wall of code isn't all that helpful. The text of the error message, however, *would* be helpful.

Comment: -1 for failing to provide any details **after two days**.

Comment: i was upload error image to imageshack site. http://img513.imageshack.us/img513/9794/errorz.png this is what i received error thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me like you're printing gzipped data to the command line. Possibly because the data returned by the server is not being decompressed by urllib when it is compiled to an exe.

Try manually removing the Accept-Encoding header, this would prevent the server from returning compressed data and prevent your script from failing. You might also want to try urllib2 or another solution to download the data from the web.